# How to subscribe to update,delete and inserts on a mysql table?

Tags: mysql, logging, mariadb, mysqlbinlog

I would like to get a notification when in certain mysql (or mariadb) tables (innodb) updates,inserts or  deletes happen.

I need to track these changes from another process as soon as possible,

I was thinking maybe I could subscribe to the mysql binary log?
Can somebody explain how this can be done? 
Is there for example a  log read API that mysql offers?

Does the game change when I use a Galera cluster?

Comment: Thinking about the problem again. Since I am in another process and this process can crash I think that subscribing to the binary log is the only feasible way....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use mysqlbinlog with --stop-never option to get all insert, update, and delete statements ([mysqlbinlog documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqlbinlog.html#option_mysqlbinlog_stop-never)).

You may use the C++ library [MySQL Replication Listener](https://launchpad.net/mysql-replication-listener) that is based on the binlog api.

Answer (score 1):

`TRIGGER` is your friend here. From MySQL-Doc:

> A trigger is defined to activate when a statement inserts,
> updates, or deletes rows in the associated table

See [MySQL-Doc here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html), there are some examples, too.

Comment: This doesn't notify other processes, all it can do is run other queries on the database.

Comment: Isn't that all you need? Insert a `last_update_time` in a table and read the value from you application periodically.

Comment: I would then have to poll the table every second ... quite some work

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this will help you, but I like to use a separate table to track the changes.  If I have a table called "site_visitors", I'll create another table called "site_visitors_log" that is immediately written to with the information I need (IP addresses, timestamp, etc.) right after data is inserted into "site_visitors".  Very convenient.